# How to test an API request using Axios with Redux DevTools' Dispatcher?

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios

I would like to test the GET_PLANTS action using Redux DevTools' Dispatcher.

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { GET_PLANTS } from './types';

export const getPlants = () => dispatch => {
  axios.get('/api/plants').then(res =>
    dispatch({
      type: GET_PLANTS,
      payload: res.data
    })
  );
};
```

I know that my application is working correctly, as I can display the fetched data using `useDispatch()` and `useSelector()` hooks. However, I would like to be able to test the API call without having to build components.
I have tried to dispatch this action from the Dispatcher in the following ways:

```
{
  type: 'GET_PLANTS',
  payload: res.data
}
```

Throws an error:

> res is not defined

```
{
  type: 'GET_PLANTS',
  payload: axios.get('/api/plants').then(res => res.data)
}
```

Throws an error:

> axios is not defined

```
{
   type: 'GET_PLANTS',
   payload: fetch('/api/plants').then(res => res.data)
 }
```

Throws an error:

> A non-serializable value was detected in an action, in the path:
> `payload`. Value: `Promise {<pending>}` (...) To allow non-serializable values see: https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-guide#working-with-non-serializable-data

Would allowing non-serializable values be indeed a solution here? I have a hunch that I shouldn't go down that road. It would be very appreciated if you could advise on the best solution.

Comment: Looks like you need to use redux thunk to do async operations.

Comment: I'm using Redux Toolkit so redux thunk is included out-of-the-box. And as I said, I am able to fetch the data using useDispatch(), I'm just not able to test it/ fetch it with the Redux DevTools.

Comment: Ah I see your point now, then just ignore my answer, because this is not what you are looking for. 

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a Redux Thunk Action. With the Redux Toolkit you have it actually build-in. So you can do it like this:

[Redux Toolkit Thunk Documentation](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk)

```js
import { createAsyncThunk } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import axios from 'axios';
import { GET_PLANTS } from './types';

export const getPlants = createAsyncThunk(GET_PLANTS, () => {
  return axios.get('/api/plants').then(res =>
    res.data;
  );
});
```